# Reverse proxy with parameters

Tags: nginx, reverse

am looking into setting up a reverse proxy with Nginx which would take the 2 parameters in the URL (namely port and IP) to be able to access them.

So far, did not succeed, here is excerpt

```
  location /([0-9]+)\/(.*)+$ {
        proxy_pass http://$2:$1/;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
   }
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: You are missing a `~`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, the correct final one (for archives) is       `location ~ /(?<targetport>[^/]+)/(?<targethost>[^/]+) {
            proxy_pass http://$targethost:$targetport/;}`

Answer (score 0):

the correct final one (for archives) is

```
location ~ /(?<targetport>[^/]+)/(?<targethost>[^/]+) 
{
proxy_pass http://$targethost:$targetport/;
}
```

Thanks